# Pandas: how to augment an element in one column based on the number of elements in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe **df** with 2 fields - **subject-percentage** and **subject-code**.
Both have a lot of `NaN` values. Now I want to make sure that the elements in **subject-percentage** field total to a 100 in each row. If they don't then I'd like to add a new element in the **subject-percentage** field which is equal to `100 - sum(elements in subject-percentage column)`. Doing so, I also want to add a dummy element (say '0') in the **subject-code** column so that at any point in time the number of elements in both these columns is same for every record.

Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```py
In[1] : df = pd.DataFrame({'subject-percentage':['10;40;40', np.nan,'25;25;50',np.nan,'50;40','20;60'],\
'subject-code':['101;202;303',np.nan,'404;505;606',np.nan,'707;808','909;10010']})
In[2] : df
Out[2]: subject-percentage subject-code
0                 10;40;40  101;202;303
1                      NaN          NaN
2                 25;25;50  404;505;606
3                      NaN          NaN
4                    50;40      707;808
5                    20;60    909;10010
```

Below is the code I used to fill-in the missing element from **subject-percentage** to make sum of all elements in each row equal to a total of 100:

```py
In [3]:def make_it_100(values):
           arr= []
           for value in values.split(';'):
               arr.append(int(value))
           arr = numpy.array(arr)
           if arr.sum() != 100:
               corrected_arr = numpy.append(arr, [100 - arr.sum()])
               corrected_arr = [str(a) for a in corrected_arr]
               return ';'.join(corrected_arr)
           else:
               return values

In [4]:df.loc[~df['sector-percentage'].isna(), 'subject-percentage'] = df.loc[~df['sector-percentage'].isna(), \
'subject-percentage'].apply(lambda x: make_it_100(x))
```

But now the two columns don't have equal no. of elements in each row. So what I want is to add a `'0'` at the end of the rows where the length of **subject-code** is less than the length of **subject-percentage**. I tried simple concatenation of `';0'` at the end of the rows in **subject-code** after slicing these rows where the length of **subject-code** is less than **subject-percentage** but then I get into the error of `'float' object has no attribute 'len'`.

Can someone tell me a more efficient way of doing the same task in one go? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: does my answer satisfy your question?

Comment: @JamesSteele your's is a much more simplified approach. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the following approach:

> Iterate through the rows of the dataframe   If the subject-percentage
>   is not null:
>       If the sum of subject-percentage is not 100:
>           concatenate the required percentage to make it 100
>           concatenate ';0' to the subject-code

implementation:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row['subject-percentage']):
        continue
    total = sum(map(int,row['subject-percentage'].split(';')))
    if total != 100:
        df.loc[index, 'subject-percentage'] = row['subject-percentage'] + ';{}'.format(100-total)
        df.loc[index, 'subject-code'] = row['subject-code'] + ';0'

subject-percentage   subject-code
0        10;40;40;10  101;202;303;0
1                NaN            NaN
2           25;25;50    404;505;606
3                NaN            NaN
4           50;40;10      707;808;0
5           20;60;20    909;10010;0
```